# Use 64 bit lib in 32 bit code

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I am wondering whether there exists a way to use a 64 bit lib in a 32bit executable.
I can design the 64 bit lib accordingly hence expose specific APIs for that purpose
that will have explicit 32 bit aligned variable in them, if that will help.

Basically we have a large piece of software which is compiled 32 bit, and for the time being 
we do not want to recompile it as 64 bit, since it will cause a lot of headache.

Now within that existing code we'd like to access a new API that we are building, that new API is hiding a 64bit implementation, but the API itself 32bit on the "outside"

We've been toying around with ideas such as remote execution or passing the data via sockets but that will be simply to slow for our purposes, using shared memory as IPC between 32/64 bits would be quite challenging to develop hence not worth the development effort.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have any choice other than IPC

Comment: Switching execution environment from 32-bit to 64-bit within same process require flipping a bit in the system descriptor, AFAIK no sane OS and toolchain dare to support this in user-space application, it's only possible if you are in charge of the kernel, but then it generate smell.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... I guess it will after all require some form of IPC, as much as we are trying to escape this solution. What should work best performance wise (under a simple effort) unix sockets?

Comment: Actually after thinking about this, why shouldn't this work in theory. If I compile with a lib which was built to work in 64 bit environment, and pass it data that is either 32 bit and is expected to be 32 bit or aligned to 64 bits, why can't it work? If my function foo which is the interface to the lib accepts for instance uint32, how will the lib be affected by the 32bit state of the host process?

Comment: It's not just the data you pass. The compiled form of 64-bit code is different than 32-bit. A 32-bit process attempting to execute 64-bit compiled code, might as well be trying to process a random binary sequence.